# How to train a predictor using linear regression and report the MAPE of leave-one-out cross-validation?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called auto with 1436 rows. I am supposed to use linear regression to train a model and report the MAPE of leave-one-out cross-validation. I wrote the code below and run it, but the result is NaN. Could anyone help me figure out what I should do? Thanks a lot!

```
library(MLmetrics)
# train a predictor using linear regression and report the MAPE of leave-one-out cross-validation
set.seed(1234)
nFold=nrow(auto)
valNum <- floor(runif(nrow(auto))*nFold)

getAutoMAPE <- function(modelCall){
  for (k in nFold){
    trainingData <- subset(auto,valNum!=k)
    validationData <- subset(auto,valNum==k)
    model <- update(modelCall,data=trainingData)
    modelPerformance <- MAPE(predict(model,validationData),validationData$Price)
  }
  modelPerformance
}

getAutoMAPE(lm(Price~.,data = auto))
```